# Get value using python selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

How am I able to extract the value "**document sent**" from the following html code using python library selenium
see code i tried which returns None

```
print driver.find_element_by_id('errorMessage').get_attribute("value")
```

**html code:**

```
<TABLE>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD id=errorMessage>Document sent. </TD>
</TR>
</TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: I believe you want `find_element_by_id('errorMessage').text` .

Comment: tried it and gives blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use below code to get required text:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

text = wait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id("errorMessage").text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("errorMessage").getText();
```

OR

```
driver.find_element_by_id("errorMessage").getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

Hope this helps..